# Node JS Unexpected character '#'

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

Node JS Unexpected character `#`.

Class:

```
export class Test{
    #parent = null;
    #name = null;

    constructor(name, parent) {
        this.#name = name;

        if (parent) {
            this.#parent = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
"start": "babel-node"
```

I am run script "start" and get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (9:4)

   7 | 
   8 | export class Test{
>  9 |     #parent = null;
     |     ^
  10 |     #name = null;
```

Versions:

```
-"@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
-"@babel/node": "^7.8.7",
-"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
-node: v12.16.2
-npm: 6.14.4
```

How fix it?

Comment: Identifiers cannot begin with a `#`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Private_field_declarations. Hope you didn't downvote the question because "Identifiers cannot begin with a #".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private fields access from "stage-3" - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

You need add to .babelrc:

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings"
  ]
```